# QGeoPath vs QGeoPolygon

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to work out the difference between the **QGeoPath** and **QGeoPolygon** classes and the reason/purpose for their coexistence. They seem to be almost identical except QGeoPath has an additional property for "width".

Documentation is also kind of copy/paste of one another in explaining their purpose, so no gain there.

When would one use the **QGeoPath** vs **QGeoPolygon**?

Searching on the internet does not yield anything that would shed a light on this. I'm surprised not to find such Q to have been asked already.

What am I missing?
Any clarification would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A path is a linear feature whereas a polygon is a closed area feature. You would use the path when you need a route and you'd use a polygon when you want an area. A path usually has a different end position to it's starting position. A path with a width does not make a polygon, just a buffer zone on either side of the centreline. They're two different concepts.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What I'm missing here is how the rest of the Qt framework differentiate between the two.
I.e. are there any other classes or methods that treat them differently? 
Who are the consumers of these two respectively?
Thanks.